# How to clone / deepcopy Python 3.x dict with internal references to the objects

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, copy, clone, metaclass

I have a following problem. Let's say we have class **A** and class **B**:

```
class A:

    def clone(self):

        return self.__class__()

class B:

    def __init__(self, ref):

        self.ref = ref

    def clone(self):

        return self.__class__(
            ref = self.ref
        )
```

I also have a class that inherits after *dict* called **Holder**.

```
class Holder(dict):

    def clone(self):

        return self.__class__(
            {k: v.clone() for k, v in self.items()}
        )
```

Now what I want is to have some way of copying the whole dict (with values already put inside) with my clone() function in the way that the references don't get messed up.

And here's some code that should clarify the behaviour that I want:

```
original = Holder()
original['a'] = A()
original['b'] = B(original['a'])  # here we create B object 
                                  # with reference to A object

assert original['a'] is original['b'].ref  # reference is working

copy = original.clone()  # we clone our dict

assert copy['a'] is copy['b'].ref  # reference is not working like I want
                                   # copy['b'].ref points to old original['b']

assert original['a'] is not copy['a']
assert original['b'] is not copy['b']
assert original['b'].ref is not copy['b'].ref
```

Here's some background to the problem described below:

> Let's say that I have a class called **MyClass** and metaclass called **MyClassMeta**.
>
> I want to supply the **__prepare__** function of **MyClassMeta** with my own *dict* that will be the instance of class called **Holder**. During the class creation I will be storing values of certain types to the internal *dict* of **Holder** instance (similarly to what EnumMeta does). Since the **Holder** instance will be filled with values during the class creation all instances of **MyClass** will be have a reference to the same object.
>
> Now what I want is to have the separate copy per instance of my **Holder**. I thought that I can just copy/clone my object but the problem came up when I added object that referenced other object inside the same dict.

Comment: How would you deal with circular references? I don't understand your spec fully. I would suggest `json`ifying nested dictionaries.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand. "You can solve every problem with another level of indirection, except for the problem of too many levels of indirection"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to clone custom data structures in Python is to implement the `__deepcopy__` special method. This is what is called by the `copy.deepcopy` function.

As explained in the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy):

> Two problems often exist with deep copy operations that don’t exist
>   with shallow copy operations:
>
> - Recursive objects (compound objects that, directly or indirectly, contain a reference to themselves) may cause a recursive loop.
> - Because deep copy copies everything it may copy too much, such as data which is intended to be shared between copies. **[This is the problem you are facing]**
>
> The `deepcopy()` function avoids these problems by:
>
> - keeping a “memo” dictionary of objects already copied during the current copying pass; and
> - letting user-defined classes override the copying operation or the set of components copied.

### Code

```
import copy

class A:
    def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
        return self.__class__()

class B:
    def __init__(self, ref):
        self.ref = ref

    def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
        return self.__class__(
            ref=copy.deepcopy(self.ref, memo)
        )

class Holder(dict):
    def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
        return self.__class__(
            {k: copy.deepcopy(v, memo) for k, v in self.items()}
        )
```

### Test

```
import copy

original = Holder()
original['a'] = A()
original['b'] = B(original['a'])  # here we create B object
                                  # with reference to A object

assert original['a'] is original['b'].ref  # reference is working

cp = copy.deepcopy(original)  # we clone our dict

assert cp['a'] is cp['b'].ref  # reference is still working

assert original['a'] is not cp['a']
assert original['b'] is not cp['b']
assert original['b'].ref is not cp['b'].ref
```

Comment: Thank you. This is EXACTLY what I was looking for! I wasn't aware that deepcopy can take more than one argument. What's more weird, PyCharm hints the signature of __deepcopy__ with memo parameter but when you write copy.deepcopy(org, memo) it shows that you passed unexpected parameter for some reason.

Comment: I have the same behaviour from PyCharm. This is most likely a bug